# Acts_as_taggable_on fails in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) on my rails 3.1 app. This is my model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills
 end
```

I get this error the moment I try anything with the user object.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `acts_as_taggable_on' for #<Class:0x90bfd84>
```

I even tried just using `acts_as_taggable` but didnt work. Am i doing anything wrong or is this a known issue?

Comment: Did you add `gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'` to your Gemfile and ran `bundle install` ?

Comment: Yes i did sir.. I even created a sample app and installed the plugin locally for the project. Both didnt work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using acts_as_taggable_on with rails 3.1 and it works ok. I am using acts_as_taggable 2.1.1

I defined acts_as_taggable in model I want to tag (ie Books) and acts_as_tagger in model that acts as tagger (ie User).

Gem documentation may be confusing because it tags users in the examples. ¿Do you want to tag users or another thing?

Did you make Post Installation steps?

```
rails generate acts_as_taggable_on:migration

rake db:migrate
```

In my case looking to table in database used by acts_as_taggable_on was helpful
https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/generators/acts_as_taggable_on_migration/templates/migration.rb

Hope this helps

Comment: It was a `version` issue. I had 2.1.4, I tried with 2.1.1 and it works now. Thanx a lot.